# Mysql Collation issue for multi language concept

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, tamil

For multi language, i have tried mysql collation with "utf8_unicode_ci" and also "utf8mb4_unicode_ci", but i getting issues.

1) when i update the text by coding. the output in phpmyadmin showing  "à®Žà®®à¯à®à®ªà®¿" junk character, but the output in website is displaying correctly.

2) when i update the text by directly in phpmyadmin. the output in phpmyadmin showing correct, but the output in website is showing "??????" characters.

How to showing correct in both phpmyadmin and website?

Note: the language text is tamil text

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `utf8_general_ci` encoding for multi-language is widely used.

Also, when you need to do operation from code set character encoding to utf8 from mysql.

Hope fully it will solve your issue.

Comment: you mean to set character encoding by coding level or in phpmyadmin ?

Comment: set character encoding in coding level.